# MySQL - UNION and ORDER/SORT ROWS

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by, union

I am retrieving table result/s using MySQL's UNION feature. The table is basically containing **ordered items** from a **sales order**

Below is the query that i Used:

```
SET @meta_id=0; 
SELECT bsb.ID AS meta_id, bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_item_id, '_product_id' AS meta_key, bsb.PRODUCT_ID AS meta_value, 1 AS origin
FROM b_sale_basket bsb
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID = 255
UNION
SELECT bsb.ID AS meta_id, bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_item_id, '_qty' AS meta_key, bsb.QUANTITY AS meta_value, 2 AS origin
FROM b_sale_basket bsb
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID = 255
) sales_order_meta
```

The **first** query above **retrieves** **ordered products** having an **order_item_id** of **255**

while 
 The **second** query above **retrieves** the **quantity** of each product **ordered**

**Side Note**: In case you ask why I query them this way since they all belong in the same table, it is because I'm trying to retrieve it like **woocommerce** does to its ordered items...

The output of the query above looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPsjv.png

But, I wish to order the results so that **below each product ordered** there is a **quantity** of **each** product ordered **below** them..

The **Final result** that I want, looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx6Aw.png

Kindly Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a user-defined variable to give a rank for each individual query so first row query 1 will have a rank of 1 and similarly first row of second query will have a rank of 1 and then 2 ,3 so on and then order your result by this row number

```
SELECT bsb.ID AS meta_id, bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_item_id, '_product_id' AS meta_key, bsb.PRODUCT_ID AS meta_value, 1 AS origin
,@r:= @r +1 AS `row`
FROM b_sale_basket bsb,(SELECT @r:=0) t
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID = 255
UNION
SELECT bsb.ID AS meta_id, bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_item_id, '_qty' AS meta_key, bsb.QUANTITY AS meta_value, 2 AS origin
,@r:= @r +1 AS `row`
FROM b_sale_basket bsb,(SELECT @r:=0) t
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID = 255
ORDER BY `row`
```

**Edit**

You can also try `ORDER BY order_item_id,meta_key`

Comment: Hello Khalid, Thanks for your response. Thanks for the suggestion. I understand what you mean. I tried your example but the column rows returns 1,2,3,4 sequentially.. do you have another idea how to achieve the final output?

Comment: Hi Khalid. Thanks for your suggestion. I got the correct output.